# Cassandra table is huge compared to initial data files

Tags: cassandra, compression, storage, bigdata

We are trying to analyse timeseries coming from several sensors. We are at the moment evaluating storage into Cassandra, as performances are told to be great.

Our sensors records are first stored locally into two binary files : one stores the timestamps, the other stores the measures. These two files are about 2MB in total, to store 700,000 measures for one sensor.

We are then reading data from those files and storing the information in Cassandra with the following data model :

```
    CREATE TABLE data (
        sensor_id text,
        tps timestamp,
        value double,
        PRIMARY KEY ((sensor_id), tps),
    ) WITH compression = {'sstable_compression' : 'DeflateCompressor'};
```

This table store the same data as in the two binary files, but the size of the associated sstable is about 10.4MB (statistics from `nodetool cfstats data -H`, line `Space used (live)`or `Space used (total)`, for only one sensor). We tried to reduce the volume of the table by setting the TIMESTAMP to 0 (using `INSERT INTO data (sensor_id, tps, value) VALUES ('station_123_sensor_456', '2010-06-01 10:20:30.456+0000', 0.123456789) USING TIMESTAMP 0`, even if we know the risks about handling duplicated data. With this, we reached a table volume of about 6.7MB, which is still 4 times bigger than the original files.

Is it the price to pay to have great read/write performances, or is there a better way to store the data in Cassandra (by removing the TIMESTAMP for instance)?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What version of Cassandra are you using?

Comment: Cassandra 2.2.7